# Changing font on xml radio buttons

Tags: xml, radio-button

I'm trying to add radio buttons on an xml file. I can get the radio buttons to appear, however, the text appears in a different style/size. I've tried adding a label style (seen in the first row of syntax) but it didn't change anything. Any suggestions?

New
Add
Replace

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. I had to create a label tag on the CSS file and then add the tag to the label fields in the radio button code.

CSS file:

label.ex1 {font: 12px arial; color:#555;}

HTML File:

```
    <label class="ex1" for="swEmployee">Student Worker</label>
```